# change achemso style in chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I have a root file and a separate `chapter.tex` and chapter.bib for each chapter (per the `chapterbib` setup: I am not using the `achemso` package).

Root file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{thesis}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

Chapter 1 (as a separate tex file)

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Text goes here\cite{person2013malaria}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{./Bibliographies/chapter1}
```

Bib file (as a separate `.bib` file saved to the appropriate directory above)

```
@article{person2013malaria,
title={Malaria},
author={Person, One and Person, Two and Person, Three and Person, Four and Person, Five and Person, Six and Person, Seven and Person, Eight and Person, Nine and Person, Ten and Person, Eleven},
journal={J. Amer. Med. Assoc.},
volume={25},
number={2},
pages={160},
year={2013},
publisher={LWW}
}
```

I am trying to control my `achemso` style bibliography with the following command:

```
@Control{achemso-control,
ctrl-article-title = "yes",
ctrl-chapter-title = "no",
ctrl-etal-number = "99",
ctrl-etal-firstonly = "no",
}
```

...with no success.  Not sure if I'm putting it in the wrong location (have tried adding it directly to the `.bib` file, saved as a separate `.bib` file (`chapter1-control.bib`) and calling it in with the `\bibliography` command.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the control system by hand, there are two things to do:

- Include a `@Control` entry in one of your databases
- Cite that control entry (using `\nocite`, so no text is printed)

If you are using multiple bibliographies, the magic citation needs to apply to each one. Thus a minimal working example would be something like:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-chapter-one}
\nocite{achemso-control}% Special citation here
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Text goes here\cite{person2013malaria}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{\jobname-chapter-one} 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-chapter-one.bib}
@article{person2013malaria,
title={Malaria},
author={Person, One and Person, Two and Person, Three and Person, Four and Person, Five and Person, Six and Person, Seven and Person, Eight and Person, Nine and Person, Ten and Person, Eleven},
journal={J. Amer. Med. Assoc.},
volume={25},
number={2},
pages={160},
year={2013},
publisher={LWW}
}

@Control{achemso-control,
ctrl-article-title = "yes",
ctrl-chapter-title = "no",
ctrl-etal-number = "99",
ctrl-etal-firstonly = "no",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\include{\jobname-chapter-one}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've included the special `\nocite{achemso-control}` citation at the start of the file. Also, importantly, notice that `achemso` is a `natbib`-based bibliography style, so you *cannot* use the `cite` package and must use the appropriate set up in `natbib`.

In the above, I've included the special entry in the same `.bib` file as the real citations. You don't have to do that, and indeed the way the `achemso` package does things is to create a dedicated `.bib` file with just this one entry in it. If you do that, a demo might look like:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-chapter-one}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\nocite{achemso-control}
Text goes here\cite{person2013malaria}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{\jobname-control,\jobname-chapter-one} 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-chapter-one.bib}
@article{person2013malaria,
title={Malaria},
author={Person, One and Person, Two and Person, Three and Person, Four and Person, Five and Person, Six and Person, Seven and Person, Eight and Person, Nine and Person, Ten and Person, Eleven},
journal={J. Amer. Med. Assoc.},
volume={25},
number={2},
pages={160},
year={2013},
publisher={LWW}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-control.bib}
@Control{achemso-control,
ctrl-article-title = "yes",
ctrl-chapter-title = "no",
ctrl-etal-number = "99",
ctrl-etal-firstonly = "no",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\include{\jobname-chapter-one}
\end{document}
```

where the same control database can then be used by each chapter (you still need to cite it in each one!).

Comment: strangely, when I replace {cite} with {natbib}, it does not compile, giving the error \newblock undefined with reference to this line in the bbl - \begin{thebibiliography}{10}.  With {cite}, it compiles fine but does not read the control sequence (et al still used, etc).  And of course, thank you for your time

Comment: @nihjhu This may be down to your document class: I have used `article` as there are several `thesis.cls` files about. `\newblock` should be provided by your class, but `\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand{\newblock}{}}`  should deal with any errors.